# Xcode 7.1 with iOS 9.1 error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'Parse.PFGeoPoint'

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, module, frameworks

After updating my xcode to 7.1, I get this error:

```
include of non-modular header inside framework module 'Parse.PFGeoPoint'
```

which does not let 'Parse' module to build. I set "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules" in Target to Yes but it is not helping. I guess it is a swift compiler error. Do you have any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go To build settings and under Target search for `Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules` and set that to yes.

---

Note: If you're using CocoaPods. run

1. `[sudo] gem install cocoapods`
2. `pod install`